# Should measurable cardinals be regular?

Tags: set-theory, definition, large-cardinals

I know that there are two very similar questions here, one asking if the condition of $\kappa$ being a regular cardinal in the definition of $\kappa$-complete filter is really needed and another asking about the definition of measurable cardinals, but my doubt is when I put those definitions together.

According to Wikipedia and Jech, in the definition of measurable cardinal, $\kappa$ doesn't need to be regular, just uncountable, but the definition of $\kappa$-complete filter ask for it. So what am I missing here? Should $\kappa$ be regular or not? Sorry for the noob question and thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you require an *ultrafilter* not just a filter. But yes. Regularity follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be a nonprincipal, $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Then $\kappa$ is regular.

Proof. 
First note that $U$ is uniform, i.e. every member of $A \in U$ has size $\kappa$. (Otherwise $A = \bigcup_{\xi \in A } \{\xi \}$ is a union of length $< \kappa$ so that by $\kappa$-completeness we must have $\{\xi\} \in U$ for some $\xi \in A$.)

Suppose $\kappa$ is singular. Write $\kappa = \bigcup_{\xi < \eta} A_\xi$, with $A_\xi$ of cardinality $< \kappa$ and $\eta < \kappa$. Since $U$ is uniform, we have $A_\xi \not \in U$ for all $\xi < \eta$. But then, by $\kappa$-completeness,
$$
\emptyset = \bigcap_{\xi < \eta} \kappa \setminus A_\xi \in U.
$$
Contradiction. $\dashv$

Comment: But how can you say that $U$ is a $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter if I don't that $\kappa$ is regular in the first place?

Comment: @MarinUW You don't need the regularity of $\kappa$ in the definition of $\kappa$-completeness. It just means that whenever you have a sequence $(A_\xi \mid \xi < \eta)$ with $\eta < \kappa$ and $A_{\xi} \in U$ for all $\xi < \eta$, then $\bigcap_{\xi < \eta} A_{\xi} \in U$. If $U$ is nonprincipal, this implies the regularity of $\kappa$ (and nonprincipality is needed here).

Comment: Yes, you used nonpricipality proving uniformity, but if I understood correctly, Asaf showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363399/question-about-definition-of-kappa-completeness-of-filter?rq=1) that if $\kappa$ in singular, then you can construct a sequence < cf$(\kappa)$ such that the intersection is not in $U$.

Comment: @MarinUW Yes, that's pretty much the same idea. Unless $U$ (on $\kappa$) is principal, it cannot be $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)+1$-complete. Hence, if you have a nonprincipal ultrafilter that is $\kappa$-complete, $\kappa$ must be regular. There's not tension between Asaf's and my argument.